# SSHException Error reading SSH protocol banner with ParallelSSHClient

Tags: python, robotframework, paramiko

I'm using ParallelSSHClient to connect to multiple servers.
When I'm running the Python function, it is working perfectly.
However, when I'm calling the function from a test case in Robot Framework, I'm getting the following error.

> SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner('This operation would
>   block forever', )

The Python function I have used is:

```
from pssh.pssh_client import ParallelSSHClient
from pssh.utils import load_private_key
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
def check101():
    pkey = load_private_key('/root/test.pem')
    hosts = ['2.2.2.2', '1.1.1.1']
    client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, pkey=pkey)

    try: 
            output = client.run_command("<command>")
    except (AuthenticationException):
            print 'Error'
    node=0
    for host in output:
            for line in output[host].stdout:
                    node=node+1
                    if (int(line)>0):
                            return node
                            break
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the start-

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```